# Linking the orders of an ARMA and ARIMA representation of a unit root process

Tags: arima

If $\Delta Y_t$ can be described by a (stationary) $ARMA(p,q)$ process, then $Y_t$ can be described by an $ARIMA(p,1,q)$ process. Theoretically (concerns of usefulness aside), does this mean we can consider $Y_t$ as a (non-stationary) $ARMA(p+1,q)$ with a unit root in its autoregressive component?
I'm trying to get a sense of how autoregressive, moving average, and integrated orders of a unit root process are linked to each other in its $ARMA$ and $ARIMA$ representations. To my understanding, it's purely an issue of notation. If it's not, please let me know.

Comment: Hi:  If the coefficient is equal to 1, then it's not considered a "p" coefficient. It's considered part of "d". But I could see how it could be confusing to someone first seeing the notation. And yes, you're understand is correct in that it's an issue of notation. But note that a coefficient that is truly 1.0, can't be estimated like coefficients that are less than 1.0. Actually, the coefficients that are 1.0 are not estimated at all. One needs to see if the series is non-stationary. If it is not, but the difference is, then the series needs to be differenced and that "coefficient" is 1.0.

Comment: Thanks so much! So if we want to model $Y_t$ using the Box-Jenkins method, we must first check its stationarity. If $Y_t$ is found to be non-stationary, but becomes stationary when differenced once, the usual practice is to model $Y_t$ as an $ARIMA(p,1,q)$ process rather than a non-stationary $ARMA$ because the unit root cannot be considered a part of the autoregressive component of $Y_t$. Is that correct?

Comment: That's absolutely correct. ARMA models have to be made stationary ( into ARIMA models )  before any of the ARMA stuff can be applied.  box-jenkins-reinsel is ( or atleast used to be. it's been a while :). ) the bible text for arima.  chris chatfield has  written somewhat less technical ( than box jenkins ) but still insightful books about it.

Comment: just one more thing: differencing once might make the series stationary. there are rare cases where differencing twice might be needed. Then, there are also cases where nothing works. For example,  try making the price series of some stock stationary. The  trick there is to difference the log prices so sometimes a transform can help.